# PostSharp automapper

Tags: .net, postsharp

is there any options how to do this with PostSharp?

```
class MyObject
{
    public User User {get; set;}
    public MyObject()
    { 
         User = new User();
    }

    public static FromMyObjectDTO(MyObjectDTO myObjectDTO)
    {
         //This should be by PostSharp, I want use this in many class, but I do not want use reflection
         return new MyObject{User.Name = myObjectDTO.UserName };
    }
}

class MyObjectDTO
{
    public string UserName {get; set;}
}
```

I find some question on StackOverflow, but it was from 2009, thats why I asking again.

Comment: You mean you want to implement the body of `FromMyObjectDTO` automatically? How do you want to use the method? Does the class and it's DTO counterpart have same properties? Please try to explain in more detail as it is not clear (to me) what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

If you create an aspect, you are intended to make it general, so you can apply it in many classes (as you said you wanted). Otherwise, it doesn't worth to create an aspect, but to write the code directly in the method inside the class (what you're trying to avoid).

If the aspect doesn't know all the class's types where it can be applied  (and it shouldn't!) nor its DTO's, how could this aspect even know which fields (properties) to set, or where to get the values from?

I think you must use reflection. I don't see another way. This is the way you can have knowledge about existence of fields and properties in objects. (And by *you* I mean *the aspect*).